# Single-spa `cannot set properties of undefined` on hot reload

Tags: single-spa

I'm using vue-2 project inside of single-spa application, and I'm getting this error on every HOT reload for the project. Although the reload itself seems to work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many things finally found a solution. Your root single-spa config should use the same webpack version as your vue app

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this what exactly was the issue? I have the same problem now with Federated modules.